# How can i fix keyboard and trackpad on my Surface Laptop 3?

Tags: surface

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but i have some problems with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Surface Laptop 3. In the GRUB all works but ,when the OS starts, the keyboard, the trackpad and touchpad don't work and i have to use an external USB keyboard and USB mouse. Can someone help me? I'm a rookie on Linux and i don't know where to put my hands

Comment: I've solved with this https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to run it on a surface laptop 3 (intel).
there's a few steps

1. Use a external mouse and keyboard to install ubuntu [step to step here](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#installation)
2. You need to install a custom kernel (it's only a few copy/paste). It's [on the same page](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#surface-kernel-installation) and follow the Debian steps.
3. the last issue is to [enable the reboot](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Surface-Laptop-3#rebooting-gets-stuck-at-the-surface-logo)

Let me know if you get stuck somewhere

Comment: Yes i've solved it with the link in the previous comment, thanks!